# Wrap intro std function

Tags: c++, std-function

So, I have no reason to use `std::function` for this statement. Just from what I read the following statement can be written using `std::function`.

How should this statement look like? Written with `std::function`

```
template <class T>
class CFooTemplate
{
public:
    typedef void (T::*FOO_STATE)(void);
```

Explain a little, the logic behind writing.

Comment: We don't have enough context to help you with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but I'll give it a stab.

> How should this statement look like? Written with `std::function`

If I understand correctly, you mean this line: `typedef void (T::*FOO_STATE)(void);`

In this case, you would write `typedef std::function<void()> FOO_STATE;`

This is because you're using a pointer to a (member) function. The signature of the function itself is `void()`, which in C++ is equivalent to `void(void)` as you used.

`std::function` takes the raw signature (e.g. `void()` or `void(void)`) and creates a polymorphic wrapper for any function of that general signature, be it a normal function, member function, or function-like object.